# hbase.DoNotRetryIOException while reading using phoenix?

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix, sqlline

Hbase Version : 1.1.3
Phoenix Version : 4.7.0

After upserting the data I was able to read the data from Hbase using phoenix.

After restarting the cluster I'm getting the following error

Sqlline log

```
0: jdbc:phoenix:localhost> select count(*) from PRICEDATA;
    16/06/01 12:39:39 WARN ipc.CoprocessorRpcChannel: Call failed on IOException
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: PRICEDATA: at index 10
        at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.createIOException(ServerUtil.java:87)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.getTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:484)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService.callMethod(MetaDataProtos.java:11705)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.execService(HRegion.java:7606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execServiceOnRegion(RSRpcServices.java:1890)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execService(RSRpcServices.java:1872)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:32389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:108)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: at index 10
        at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.checkElementNotNull(ImmutableList.java:311)
        at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.construct(ImmutableList.java:302)
        at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:278)
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.PTableImpl.init(PTableImpl.java:424)
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.PTableImpl.<init>(PTableImpl.java:315)
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.PTableImpl.makePTable(PTableImpl.java:303)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.getTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:883)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.buildTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:501)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.doGetTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:2481)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.doGetTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:2426)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.getTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:451)
        ... 10 more

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.getRemoteException(ProtobufUtil.java:284)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.execService(ProtobufUtil.java:1611)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel$1.call(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:93)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel$1.call(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:90)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:93)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.callExecService(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:96)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CoprocessorRpcChannel.callMethod(CoprocessorRpcChannel.java:57)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService$Stub.getTable(MetaDataProtos.java:7891)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$7.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1271)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$7.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable$17.call(HTable.java:1608)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException): org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: PRICEDATA: at index 10
        at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.createIOException(ServerUtil.java:87)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.getTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:484)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService.callMethod(MetaDataProtos.java:11705)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.execService(HRegion.java:7606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execServiceOnRegion(RSRpcServices.java:1890)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execService(RSRpcServices.java:1872)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:32389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:108)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: at index 10
        at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.checkElementNotNull(ImmutableList.java:311)
        at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.construct(ImmutableList.java:302)
        at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:278)
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.PTableImpl.init(PTableImpl.java:424)
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.PTableImpl.<init>(PTableImpl.java:315)
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.PTableImpl.makePTable(PTableImpl.java:303)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.getTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:883)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.buildTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:501)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.doGetTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:2481)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.doGetTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:2426)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.getTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:451)
        ... 10 more

        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.call(RpcClient.java:1457)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.callBlockingMethod(RpcClient.java:1661)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(RpcClient.java:1719)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.execService(ClientProtos.java:30411)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.execService(ProtobufUtil.java:1607)
        ... 14 more
    16/06/01 12:39:39 WARN client.HTable: Error calling coprocessor service org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService for row \x00\x00PRICEDATA
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: PRICEDATA: at index 10
        at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.createIOException(ServerUtil.java:87)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.getTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:484)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService.callMethod(MetaDataProtos.java:11705)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.execService(HRegion.java:7606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execServiceOnRegion(RSRpcServices.java:1890)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execService(RSRpcServices.java:1872)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:32389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:108)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: at index 10
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.checkElementNotNull(ImmutableList.java:311)
        at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.construct(ImmutableList.java:302)
        at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:278)
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.PTableImpl.init(PTableImpl.java:424)
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.PTableImpl.<init>(PTableImpl.java:315)
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.PTableImpl.makePTable(PTableImpl.java:303)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.getTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:883)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.buildTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:501)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.doGetTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:2481)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.doGetTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:2426)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.getTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:451)
        ... 10 more

        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.coprocessorService(HTable.java:1620)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.coprocessorService(HTable.java:1577)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.metaDataCoprocessorExec(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1006)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.getTable(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1257)
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.updateCache(MetaDataClient.java:350)
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.updateCache(MetaDataClient.java:311)
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.updateCache(MetaDataClient.java:307)
        at org.apache.phoenix.compile.FromCompiler$BaseColumnResolver.createTableRef(FromCompiler.java:333)
        at org.apache.phoenix.compile.FromCompiler$SingleTableColumnResolver.<init>(FromCompiler.java:237)
        at org.apache.phoenix.compile.FromCompiler.getResolverForQuery(FromCompiler.java:160)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$ExecutableSelectStatement.compilePlan(PhoenixStatement.java:340)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$ExecutableSelectStatement.compilePlan(PhoenixStatement.java:330)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$1.call(PhoenixStatement.java:240)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$1.call(PhoenixStatement.java:235)
        at org.apache.phoenix.call.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:53)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeQuery(PhoenixStatement.java:234)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.execute(PhoenixStatement.java:1100)
        at sqlline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:822)
        at sqlline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:732)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:808)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:681)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:398)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:292)
    Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: PRICEDATA: at index 10
        at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.createIOException(ServerUtil.java:87)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.getTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:484)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService.callMethod(MetaDataProtos.java:11705)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.execService(HRegion.java:7606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execServiceOnRegion(RSRpcServices.java:1890)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execService(RSRpcServices.java:1872)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:32389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:108)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: at index 10
        at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.checkElementNotNull(ImmutableList.java:311)
        at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.construct(ImmutableList.java:302)
        at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:278)
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.PTableImpl.init(PTableImpl.java:424)
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.PTableImpl.<init>(PTableImpl.java:315)
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.PTableImpl.makePTable(PTableImpl.java:303)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.getTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:883)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.buildTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:501)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.doGetTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:2481)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.doGetTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:2426)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.getTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:451)
        ... 10 more

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.getRemoteException(ProtobufUtil.java:284)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.execService(ProtobufUtil.java:1611)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel$1.call(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:93)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel$1.call(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:90)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:93)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.callExecService(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:96)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CoprocessorRpcChannel.callMethod(CoprocessorRpcChannel.java:57)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService$Stub.getTable(MetaDataProtos.java:7891)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$7.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1271)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$7.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable$17.call(HTable.java:1608)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

HBASE Region server Log

```
2016-06-01 13:07:47,467 INFO  [B.defaultRpcServer.handler=6,queue=0,port=16201] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Process identifier=hconnection-0x574b597 connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=HMECL001076:2181
2016-06-01 13:07:47,467 INFO  [B.defaultRpcServer.handler=6,queue=0,port=16201] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=HMECL001076:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x574b5970x0, quorum=HMECL001076:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
2016-06-01 13:07:47,468 INFO  [B.defaultRpcServer.handler=6,queue=0,port=16201-SendThread(HMECL001076:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server HMECL001076/127.0.1.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2016-06-01 13:07:47,470 INFO  [B.defaultRpcServer.handler=6,queue=0,port=16201-SendThread(HMECL001076:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to HMECL001076/127.0.1.1:2181, initiating session
2016-06-01 13:07:47,475 INFO  [B.defaultRpcServer.handler=6,queue=0,port=16201-SendThread(HMECL001076:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server HMECL001076/127.0.1.1:2181, sessionid = 0x1550abc32310033, negotiated timeout = 40000
2016-06-01 13:07:47,481 INFO  [B.defaultRpcServer.handler=6,queue=0,port=16201] client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closing zookeeper sessionid=0x1550abc32310033
2016-06-01 13:07:47,483 INFO  [B.defaultRpcServer.handler=6,queue=0,port=16201] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x1550abc32310033 closed
2016-06-01 13:07:47,483 INFO  [B.defaultRpcServer.handler=6,queue=0,port=16201-EventThread] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
2016-06-01 13:07:47,485 ERROR [B.defaultRpcServer.handler=6,queue=0,port=16201] coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl: getTable failed
java.lang.NullPointerException: at index 10
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.checkElementNotNull(ImmutableList.java:311)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.construct(ImmutableList.java:302)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:278)
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.PTableImpl.init(PTableImpl.java:424)
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.PTableImpl.<init>(PTableImpl.java:315)
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.PTableImpl.makePTable(PTableImpl.java:303)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.getTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:883)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.buildTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:501)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.doGetTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:2481)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.doGetTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:2426)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.getTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:451)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService.callMethod(MetaDataProtos.java:11705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.execService(HRegion.java:7606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execServiceOnRegion(RSRpcServices.java:1890)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execService(RSRpcServices.java:1872)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:32389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:108)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I did Try manually scanning the hbase table and was able to retrieve the data using hbase shell. But via phoenix api I'm unable to write or read the data. This error did occur previously restarting the nodes fixed the issue previously. But currently its not working. Its only causing trouble with certain tables. all the tables nearly have the same schema.

Table Create Query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Pricedata (
    NUM_11 DOUBLE,
    D81 VARCHAR,
    D83 DOUBLE,
    D82 VARCHAR,
    D77 VARCHAR NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NUM_9 DOUBLE,
    D80 VARCHAR,
    D79 BIGINT,
    D78 BIGINT,
    NUM_10 DOUBLE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that something got corrupted or did not upgrade properly. Use HBase shell to disable and delete Phoenix's SYSTEM.CATALOG table. Phoenix will regenerate these tables upon initialization.Backup your cluster first ;)

And Run your create table Command again to restore the table.

Comment: I disabled and deleted the catalog files but phoenix hasn't regenerated these tables even after a restarting the node

Comment: It should do that if it manages to startup successfully. I'm guessing that it still hasn't?

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the data from SYSTEM.CATALOG table, you need to re-run the phoenix create sqls. This is to re-populate the metadata in CATALOG table.